# How do you check your web apps look like?

Tags: responsive-design

I've created a basic web-app which guides user to decide first programming language. I've created my project checking through Google Dev Tools iPhone6 view since I'm using iPhone6 also but in real iPhones appearance is not even look close. Is this annoyance only for me or for everyone also? or is there better way to design a web app for mobile? You should check difference from here  https://ibb.co/Gcsjsvn and check my repo from https://github.com/kgokdemir/firstlang

Comment: Well, if you're using a computer running macOS, you could use the iOS simulator that comes packaged with Xcode, and you can run Android simulator on pretty much anything.

Comment: I'm using Windows

Comment: Chrome devtools doesn't really emulate the iPhone 6, it just displays the screen at a size that matches the iPhone screen.

It will not show you all the CSS quirks specific to each browser.
The only way to be sure is to test on a real device like you did or pay a service like browerstack (there are other cheaper ones but haven't tested them) which enables you to test your website on real + emulated devices.